# Why is this assembly segfaulting?

Tags: x86, x86-64

I have two sets of x64 assembly, one of which segfaults, the other of which runs just fine.

This one runs with no problem, returning 0:

```
.global main
main:
SUBQ    $56, %rsp
PUSH    %rax
MOVQ    $0, %rax
MOVQ    $3, %r10
CMPL    %eax, %r10d
POP %rax
JGE .L3
MOVQ    $11, %rdi
CALL    raise
MOVQ    %rax, 40(%rsp)
.L3:
MOVL    $3, 32(%rsp)
ADDL    $1, 32(%rsp)
MOVQ    32(%rsp), %rdi
MOVQ    $8, %rsi
CALL    calloc
MOVQ    %rax, 40(%rsp)
MOVQ    40(%rsp), %r10
MOVL    $3, (%r10)
MOVQ    40(%rsp), %r10
MOVQ    %r10, 24(%rsp)
MOVQ    $0, %rax
ADDQ    $56, %rsp
RET
```

This one, however, segfaults (signal 11):

```
.global main
main:
SUBQ    $72, %rsp
PUSH    %rax
MOVQ    $0, %rax
MOVQ    $3, %r10
CMPL    %eax, %r10d
POP %rax
JGE .L3
MOVQ    $11, %rdi
CALL    raise
MOVQ    %rax, 40(%rsp)
.L3:
MOVL    $3, 32(%rsp)
ADDL    $1, 32(%rsp)
MOVQ    32(%rsp), %rdi
MOVQ    $8, %rsi
CALL    calloc
MOVQ    %rax, 40(%rsp)
MOVQ    40(%rsp), %r10
MOVL    $3, (%r10)
MOVQ    40(%rsp), %r10
MOVQ    %r10, 24(%rsp)
MOVL    $200, 48(%rsp)
MOVQ    $0, %rax
ADDQ    $72, %rsp
RET
```

As you can see, the only difference is the line MOVL $200, 48(%rsp) and the add/subtract from the stack pointer at the beginning and end. I have to assume it's segfaulting on 48(%rsp) somehow, but I don't see why that would be. Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that arguments to calloc were wrong because of the combination of 32-bit and 64-bit instructions so it was trying to allocate too much space, and thus returning 0.